# How to efficiently find the odds one out in a list?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list like

```
>>> l = [-10,-10,-10,-20,-10,-10]
```

Given you don't know it's -20, I want to find the position and the number of `-20` in one line or maybe two. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should specify what version of Python you are using. The answers below use Counter which was introduced in Python 2.7 There are still locations using Python 2.6.6

Comment: Thanks. You get the Counter advantage (:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will find the least-common element:

```
>>> my_list = [-10,-10,-10,-20,-10,-10]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter(my_list)
>>> min(counter, key=counter.get)
-20
```

To find the position, you could use `my_list.index(min(counter, key=counter.get))`.

Note this will not work for the odd-one-out in a list such as `[1, 2, 9999, 3, 4]`, you might like to check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510190/674039) for a case such as that.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to find the items that appear only once:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [-10,-10,-10,-20,-10,-10]
>>> [i for i, n in Counter(l).iteritems() if n == 1]
[-20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print min(l,key=l.count)
```

but its probably not that fast

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
print min(Counter(l).items(), key = itemgetter(1))[0]
```

would likely be faster

```
from itertools import takewhile
print l[len(list(takewhile(lambda x:l.count(x) != 1,l)))]
```

is probably the most efficient method ... well i dunno Counter should be fast too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Python version earlier than 2.7, the Counter would not have been installed yet. If that is the case then the answer is found at [Get the key corresponding to the minimum value within a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282823/python-get-key-with-the-least-value-from-a-dictionary)

```
mydict = dict((elem, my_list.count(elem)) for elem in my_list)
mymin = min(mydict, key=mydict.get)

print mydict
print mymin
```

OUTPUT:

```
{-20:1, -10:5}
-20
```